# preg_replace for username and e-mail as one field

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, login-script

I'd like to use a preg_replace for my username/e-mail login.
I store it in a SESSION and want to check if that data is inside 
the database. Since I'd like to give the user the opportunity to log 
in with username OR e-mail this expression gets a little freaky and 
I have no clue how to manage it. Can anyone help?

So the "$loginusername" is username (A-Za-z0-9) and ALSO e-mail! So it should 
 not replace that special characters...I have found this as the expression of 
 the e-mail:

```
([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)@([A-Za-z0-9-]+)([A-Za-z0-9.-]*[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*\.([A-Za-z){1,4}
```

and want to add this as preg_replace to the already existing:

```
preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','', $_SESSION["username"]);
```

I can't get this to work, always getting syntax error.

My code right now is:

```
if  ( !isset ($_SESSION['X5636gYGWEHidwWLOGIN'] )   )
    {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

include("includes/connectdatabase.php");

$loginusername = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','', $_SESSION["username"]);
$loginpassword = sha1(preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"])); 

$sessionvalidation= mysql_query("
                SELECT * 
                FROM gebruikers 
                WHERE username = '$loginusername' AND password = '$loginpassword' 
                OR email = '$loginusername' AND password = '$loginpassword' ");
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sessionvalidation);
if ($existCount == 0)
{
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I'll counter suggest you to retrieve the 'username' from the DB with the same WHERE clause above, and store only username (or only email as you like) in the session as login identifier.

Comment: So you say I'd better chose for only username of e-mail login possibility? Why? Security reasons?

Comment: I suggest you avoid using the dated `mysql_*` functions. Using them for new code is [discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query). More [modern alternatives](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) are available and better 
maintained. Also consider learning about 
[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with placeholders to reduce the risk of [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) without manually quoting all the strings.

Comment: `SELECT *` just to obtain a row count is overkill. If you only need the number, use `COUNT(*)` to count them on the server, or `SELECT 1 FROM …` so you can use `mysql_num_rows`. Apart from that, I agree with @KenCheung in that storing any key is enough to identify a user, so if you only store the user name, that means less work and less chances for things to become inconsistent. The user may still log in using either, but if the user logs in using a mail address, you can still create a session cookie based on the name, after retrieving that from the database.